# Why doesn't git amend warn you when there's nothing to amend?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

I oftentimes make the mistake of making a change to a file right after a commit, then running `git commit --amend` followed by a quick `git push -f origin master`

The issue, obviously, is that I never ran `git add foo.md`. So my amend didn't actually amend any of my committed code.

Question is: Why doesn't git warn you when amending a commit with no changes? Better yet, why does it even complete successfully? Is it merely behaving like a "touch" in changing the timestamp of a given commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The committer date (`%ci`) keeps being reset, even if the commit *author* date (`%ai`) remains the same:
For instance, if I commit --amend -no-edit the last commit on the Git repo, the author date remains unchanged, but I just created a *new* commit: replacing the old one with the same content, but a *different* commit date:

```
P:\git\git>git show -s --format="%ci" e0d6576639261beefb40afa52696d02f16c490ed
2012-12-11 03:42:23 +0100  <== just now

P:\git\git>git show -s --format="%ai" e0d6576639261beefb40afa52696d02f16c490ed
2012-12-07 14:18:55 -0800  <== original date when the author did commit
```

So any amend will result in a *different* SHA1.

From the [Pro-Book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html):

> - The author is the person who originally wrote the work,
> - whereas the committer is the person who last applied the work.

A `commit --amend` will always recreate a new commit, if only because the committer date is changing.

Answer (score 1):

Amend is useful for just changing the commit message or other details of the commit. So running it without any changes to the working dir makes a lot of sense. To prevent problems like this in the future, I would recommend using

```
git commit -a --amend
```

Comment: Just pointing out `-a`/`-all` tells git to stage **all files** and then amend.